# Boolean mask of None vs NaN in array of arrays

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, boolean, numpy-ndarray

I want to differentiate the None's from NaN's in a NumPy array with mixed data types. Specifically, I want to work with arrays where some elements are arrays. For example, suppose I have the following array with mixed data types, but without array elements:

```py
arr = np.array([[1,    None,      3],
                [4,       5, np.nan],
                [7, 'eight',     9]])
```

I can check what values are `None` with the following:

```py
>>> arr == None

array([[False,  True, False],
       [False, False, False],
       [False, False, False]])
```

This gets the result that I want: a Boolean mask with information about the individual elements, saying which elements are `None`. However, the snippet above doesn't work when any element in the array is another array. For example, consider this other array:

```py
arr_elem = np.array([3,3,3])
arr = np.array([[1,    None,      arr_elem],
                [4,       5,        np.nan],
                [7, 'eight',             9]])
```

Now, instead of a Boolean mask, I obtain a single Boolean value:

```
>>> arr == None

False
```

What is a vectorized way to obtain a Boolean mask that says which elements are None and not NaN in an array of arrays?

Answer (score 2):

You have an object dtype array.  `numpy` arrays are best when the dtype is numeric - both in terms of speed and extent of operations.

On top of that there are issues with testing for `None`, `np.nan` and equality tests on arrays.

`is None` is the best test for `None`.  `np.isnan` is best test for `nan`, since nothing equals `nan`, not even itself.  And equality tests on arrays can produce boolean arrays and `ambiguity` errors.

```
In [58]: arr = np.array([[1,    None,      3],
    ...:                 [4,       5, np.nan],
    ...:                 [7, 'eight',     9]])
In [59]: arr
Out[59]: 
array([[1, None, 3],
       [4, 5, nan],
       [7, 'eight', 9]], dtype=object)
In [60]: arr == None
Out[60]: 
array([[False,  True, False],
       [False, False, False],
       [False, False, False]])
```

ok, the `None` test is ok, but not `nan`:

```
In [61]: arr == np.nan
Out[61]: 
array([[False, False, False],
       [False, False, False],
       [False, False, False]])
In [62]: np.isnan(arr)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-62-25d2f1dae78d>", line 1, in <module>
    np.isnan(arr)
TypeError: ufunc 'isnan' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''
```

`isnan` works with float dtype arrays, not object dtype.

Making an array with array elements produces a warning. That's because making an array from arrays of mixed length often is a mistake.

```
In [63]: arr_elem = np.array([3,3,3])
    ...: arr1 = np.array([[1,    None,      arr_elem],
    ...:                 [4,       5,        np.nan],
    ...:                 [7, 'eight',             9]])
<ipython-input-63-6d36e87ab1a9>:2: VisibleDeprecationWarning: Creating an ndarray from ragged nested sequences (which is a list-or-tuple of lists-or-tuples-or ndarrays with different lengths or shapes) is deprecated. If you meant to do this, you must specify 'dtype=object' when creating the ndarray
  arr1 = np.array([[1,    None,      arr_elem],
In [64]: arr1
Out[64]: 
array([[1, None, array([3, 3, 3])],
       [4, 5, nan],
       [7, 'eight', 9]], dtype=object)
```

This is an object dtype array as before, except that an element is an array.

```
In [65]: arr1 == None
<ipython-input-65-2a40a08151e4>:1: DeprecationWarning: elementwise comparison failed; this will raise an error in the future.
  arr1 == None
Out[65]: False
```

It has to do the `==` test on each element.  But that test applied to the array element produces a boolean array (same as `In[60]`)

```
In [66]: arr_elem==None
Out[66]: array([False, False, False])
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Sorry but I think this doesn't answer my question. I know that the comparison works for `None` but not for `np.nan`. I know that the current test applied to an array of arrays produces a single Boolean (`False`). What I don't know (and need to know!) is how to obtain a Boolean mask/array from an array of arrays, where each element in the Boolean mask/array corresponds to an element in the original array. Does anybody know a way to do this?

Comment: I also know that this is a very edge case that is not what NumPy arrays were designed for. But I happen to have to use arrays.

Comment: You could write a function that handles all these cases for one element, and apply it to the whole array with `np.frompyfunc`,   You haave too many special cases to handle with existing code.

Comment: Oh, this is great! Thanks so much. If you write this as an answer I will accept it. Regarding performance, I just want to do a simple check `elem is None`. Do you think this will be very slow if applied to the whole array with `np.frompyfunc`?

Comment: With object dtype all operations are at list comprehension speed, more or less.

Comment: Good to know. Thanks a lot again!! I could fix my program thanks to the pointer to `np.frompyfunc`.

Comment: Great, thanks!  This works for my weird array with `True`, `False` or `None` only.  Initially I got a single `False` rather than an array from `arr == None`, but here I realised that `arr` must be a NumPy array for this to work.  The only drawback is that my editor/Flake8 complains at `arr == None`: E711 comparison to None should be `if cond is None`...  I guess I'll have to live with that.

Comment: It turns out that it is a bit harder to live with this than I thought - Flake8 also refuses a code commit though git pre-commit.